# rqt_graph is not working in my ros

Tags: ros, rospack, rqt-graph, rqt, ros-groovy

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Tutorial Link : -  http://www.ros.org/wiki/ROS/Tutorials/UnderstandingTopics

I'm installed rqt by using sudo apt-get install ros-groovy-rqt

While I'm running this command rosrun rqt_graph rqt_graph
It gives the following error message .
[rospack] couldn't find package [rqt_graph]

What may be the problem? I'm using ubuntu 11.10

I'm installed all the necessary requirements but while I run

rosrun rqt_graph rqt_graph

I got the following error message

ImportError: No module named rospack
[rospack] Error: could not find python module 'rosdep2.rospack'. is rosdep up-to-date (at least 0.10.4)?
[librospack]: error while executing command
terminate called after throwing an instance of 'pluginlib::LibraryLoadException'
what():  rospack could not find the qt_gui package containing qt_gui_cpp::Plugin
Aborted

How can I overcome from this problem?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/57210/rqt_graph-is-not-working-in-my-ros/) by [unais](https://answers.ros.org/users/4285/unais/) on ROS Answers with karma: 313 on 2013-03-05

Post score: 2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

`ros-groovy-rqt` is just the framework that rqt_graph uses. To get rqt_graph, you need to install:

```
sudo apt-get install ros-groovy-rqt-graph
```

or

```
sudo apt-get install ros-groovy-rqt-common-plugins
```

---

Originally posted by [jbohren](https://answers.ros.org/users/50/jbohren/) with karma: 5809 on 2013-03-05

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 3

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [unais](https://answers.ros.org/users/4285/unais/) on 2013-03-05**:
I'm installed this too but not find rqt graph

**Comment by [unais](https://answers.ros.org/users/4285/unais/) on 2013-03-05**:
I'm installed all this but if i run      rosrun rqt_graph rqt_graph I got the following error message                ImportError: No module named rospack
[rospack] Error: could not find python module 'rosdep2.rospack'. is rosdep up-to-date (at least 0.10.4)?
[librospack]: error while executing comma

**Comment by [unais](https://answers.ros.org/users/4285/unais/) on 2013-03-06**:
Hello still I have this error. I'm edited my Qn.

**Comment by [jbohren](https://answers.ros.org/users/50/jbohren/) on 2013-03-06**:
Can you clarify your problem by asking a new question, it looks like your issue has nothing to do with rqt_graph. It looks like your ROS environment is not set up right